# VSCode: How to debugging (launch.json) when tasks (tasks.json) running?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I want to run this debugging program in **launch.json**

```
        {
            // Must be running before launching: out/Debug/bin/chrome_public_apk gdb --ide
            "name": "Attach Android Webview",
            "type": "cppdbg", // "cppdbg" for GDB/LLDB, "cppvsdbg" for Windows Visual Studio debugger
            "request": "launch",
            "targetArchitecture": "arm64",
            "program": "/tmp/adb-gdb-support-${env:USER}/app_process",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/tmp/adb-gdb-support-${env:USER}/gdb",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "ignored",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "./../../": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "../../": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "././../../": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            // "miDebuggerArgs": " -x /tmp/adb-gdb-support-${env:USER}/gdbinit",
            // "args":["--package-name=com.bytedance.shell --output-directory=out/debug --adb=adb --device=914baf8f --pull-libs-dir=/tmp/adb-gdb-libs-914baf8f --verbose --target-arch=arm64"],
            "customLaunchSetupCommands": [
                {
                    "text": "-interpreter-exec console \"source -v /tmp/adb-gdb-support-${env:USER}/gdbinit\""
                }
            ],
            "launchCompleteCommand": "None",
            "preLaunchTask": "preReadyForWebView"
        }
```

and there is a task named preReadyForWebView, which will start running a gdb server and listening for gdb client.
**Now after launch the task, it will always waitting for the task end, but I want to start debugging after the task running about 5s or when it is listening, can anyone help me?**

Below is the detail of my tasks.json

```
        {
            "label": "preReadyForWebView",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/build/android/adb_gdb",
            "args": [
                "--package-name=com.bytedance.shell",
                "--output-directory=out/release",
                "--adb=adb",
                "--device=0C111FDD4006XG",
                "--pull-libs-dir=/tmp/adb-gdb-libs-0C111FDD4006XG",
                "--verbose",
                "--target-arch=arm64",
                "--ide"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: [Multi-target debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_multitarget-debugging)

Answer (score 1):

I found it!
Just add **"isBackground": true** in tasks.json and launch it! And choose **debug anyway** in the popup dialog, the gdb client will start debugging.